# Using lists with AutoBean

Tags: list, gwt, autobean

I have an `AutoBean` of type `GetGenericQuerySources`.

GetGenericQuerySources looks like this:

```
public class GetGenericQuerySources implements Serializable,
    GetGenericQuerySourcesInt {
  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public boolean queriesIsCurrent;

  public String seUId;

  // Sources
  public int fLsId;
  public String where;
  public List<Integer> filterBLnId;
  public List<List<String>> filterValues;
  public List<String> operators;
  ...
}
```

`GetGenericQuerySourcesInt` is the interface that I am using. `GetGenericQuerySources` implements `GetGenericQuerySourcesInt` and this is what I wrap with the AutoBean.

```
public interface GetGenericQuerySourcesInt {

  public boolean isQueriesIsCurrent();

  public void setQueriesIsCurrent(boolean queriesIsCurrent);

  public String getSeUId();

  public void setSeUId(String seUId);

  public int getfLsId();

  public void setfLsId(int fLsId);
  ...
}
```

Currently I initialize and populate the lists as follows:

```
    GetGenericQuerySourcesInt logicalNamesQryObj = bean.as();

    ...

    logicalNamesQryObj.setQueriesIsCurrent(queriesIsCurrent);
    logicalNamesQryObj.setQueryId(currentQuery.getQId());
    logicalNamesQryObj.setParameterNames(new ArrayList<String>());
    logicalNamesQryObj.setParameterValues(new ArrayList<String>());
```

How can I initialize the Lists in `GetGenericQuerySources` so that I can still use them with `AutoBean`?

Currently I initialize the lists as `new ArrayList<T>()` and then populate the `ArrayList` normally, but when I try to access the list in the `AutoBean` I get a NPE.

From what I understand this is because of the way `AutoBean` handles lists (or the lack thereof).

I tried initializing the lists to `ArrayList`, `LinkedList` and `Vector`, but to no avail.

I tried reading up on `AutoBean` over [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean), but the documentation is basically non-existent.

It would be much appreciated if someone could point me in the direction of some more in-detail documentation or if you could help me solve my issue.

Comment: What is MyObjectInterface - is that the *actual* autobean interface you are using? And how are you initializing those lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known issue. You need to wrap the items in the `List` with their own AutoBean.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11532290/1417997).